# ansible iam_user deletion does not work

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I tried to delete an user by:

```
  - name: "Remove user abc"
    iam_user:
      name: abc
      state: absent
```

it gave me following error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: DeleteConflictException: An error occurred (DeleteConflict) when calling the DeleteUser operation: Cannot delete entity, must delete access keys first.
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "error": {
        "code": "DeleteConflict", 
        "message": "Cannot delete entity, must delete access keys first.", 
        "type": "Sender"
    }, 
    "response_metadata": {
        "http_headers": {
            "content-length": "298", 
            "content-type": "text/xml", 
            "date": "Thu, 12 Jul 2018 20:53:02 GMT", 
            "x-amzn-requestid": "91913df0-8615-11e8-b3e7-b16567885120"
        }, 
        "http_status_code": 409, 
        "request_id": "91913df0-8615-11e8-b3e7-b16567885120", 
        "retry_attempts": 0
    }
}
```

MSG:

Unable to delete user intelerad-billing-mzhao-client-creator-user: An error occurred (DeleteConflict) when calling the DeleteUser operation: Cannot delete entity, must delete access keys first.

It seems there is even no ansible module to delete access key.

any hints?

Comment: by the way, I tried with ansible 2.5.4

Answer (score 5):

AWS IAM APIs are finicky when it comes to user deletion. Deletion can be blocked if the user is assigned access keys or if the user's login profile doesn't exist.

Funny enough, Ansible has two modules that you can use to delete users: [`iam`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/iam_module.html#iam-module) and [`iam_user`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/iam_user_module.html#iam-user-module), but one errors on access keys and the other errors on non-existant login profiles.

So let's go ahead and leverage AWS CLI for this one.

This playbook worked for me to create and delete a user with keys.

```
---
- name: Create / Delete IAM user with keys
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    username: foo

  tasks:
    - name: Create user with keys
      iam:
        iam_type: user
        name: "{{ username }}"
        state: present
        access_key_state: create
        key_count: 2

    - name: Get all the access keys
      shell: aws iam list-access-keys --user-name {{ username }} --query 'AccessKeyMetadata[*].AccessKeyId'
      register: access_key_list

    - name: Delete each key
      shell: aws iam delete-access-key --access-key-id {{ item }} --user-name {{ username }}
      loop: "{{ access_key_list.stdout | from_json }}"

    - name: Delete user
      iam_user:
        name: "{{ username }}"
        state: absent
```

Note that the deletion task is `iam_user`. This is because plain `iam` will error if the user login profile doesn't exist.

Hope that helps!

Comment: that's exactly what I did. Thank. I am wondering why this question is not asked before? seems no one is using ansible aws module. Btw, If using aws cli, I would not even put them in ansible, as ansible's syntax is not flexible.

Comment: I find Ansible quite flexible actually, though it does have a little bit of a learning curve. It's great for automating infrastructure management. I tend to use `shell` and AWS CLI commands together a lot and not the Ansible modules (unless I have a good reason to).